# get current taxonomy post with ajax

Tags: ajax, taxonomy

its my page-ajax.php file

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

   $terms = get_terms( 'bk-category' );
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
 }

$bkcat = $term->term_id;
     $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'category'         => $bkcat,
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'post_type'        => 'bk-post',

    );
     $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
     if($the_query->have_posts()) {
            ?>

                     $i = 1;
                     while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                     $a = $i++;

                      endwhile;
                     }
```

and this my page-table.php file

```
global $post;
  $terms = get_terms( 'bk-category' );
  $select = "n";
  $select.= "Select categoryn";

  foreach($terms as $term){
    if($term->count > 0){
        $select.= "slug."'>".$term->name."";
    }
  }

  $select.= "";

  echo $select;




$(document).ready(function() {
   var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange() {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value != -1 ) {
    $('.results').html("/images/loading.gif' />");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        dataType   : "html",
        url: "/page-ajax.php",
        success: function (data){
            $('.results').html(data);
        }
    });
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;

});
```

In this case all shows or All Categories Shows , but :
I just want to show only the contents of each category is clicked

Answer (score 1):

```
//$bkcat = $term->term_id; try to call this via post from ajax where you will pass id of category
 $args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => -1,
'category'         => $bkcat,
'order'            => 'ASC',
'post_type'        => 'bk-post',
'category_name'    => $bkcat,

);
 $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
 if($the_query->have_posts()) {
        ?>

                 $i = 1;
                 while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
                 $a = $i++;

                  endwhile;
                 }
```

In case if you have query still let me know I will explain you entire code.

Comment: tnq my frind , but its not working for me :/
I just want to show only the contents of each category is selected

please chek this url : yon.ir/2aO3

Comment: Please pass the id of the category in ajax and then  you can fetch it into my page-ajax.php using $_POST mehtod

Comment: how? Please write code

Comment: hi
Not somebody help me?

Comment: wait I am making code for you

Comment: hi . its ok ; tnq